# deploy node js on ec2 using pm2 causes error on status

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, pm2

when i try and run my node.js app using pm2 on an aws ec2 instance i keep getting this error

```
*4|app      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
4|app      |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
4|app      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
4|app      |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
4|app      |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
4|app      |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
4|app      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
4|app      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
4|app      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
4|app      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
4|app      |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
4|app      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
4|app      |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
4|app      |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
4|app      |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)*
```

I am not sure how to fix it. I have deployed a sample app from a tutorial and it does not give the error so I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am using the ubuntu 18.04 version for my OS on ec2